Add data attribute to WooCommerce script
I would like to add a data attribute to a script that is placed by the WooCommerce plugin. This is the script:
woocommerce/assets/js/select2/select2.min.js
Because Cookiebot is set to automatic for us, this script is not loaded if the Cookies are refused. This causes a problem with our checkout and can be solved if we ignore the script.
Is it possible to add this attribute to that script via a function?
data-cookieconsent="ignore"

That should solve it, but I don't know if this can be done with a function or another way.
EDIT
I tried this code but nothing happens, any ideas?
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'add_id_to_script', 10, 3 );

function add_id_to_script( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
    if ( 'select2.full.min.js' === $handle ) {
        $tag = '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . esc_url( $src ) . '" id="select2-js" data-cookieconsent="ignore"></script>';
    }

    return $tag;
}


I don't think that is the correct handle.

If this script is registered in the Wordpress script queue, you can use the filter hook script_loader_tag to alter the actual HTML script tag used to load it on the page. Here is a quick example of how you could use this filter:
add_filter('script_loader_tag', function($tag, $handle, $src){

    if($handle == '[*** SCRIPT_TAG_NAME ***]'){
        return str_replace('src', 'data-cookieconsent="ignore" src', $tag);
    } else { return $tag; }

}, 10, 3)

From the WordPress documentation:

Filters the HTML script tag of an enqueued script.

How does this work
This filter hook provides access to the WordPress function which builds the HTML script tag responsible for loading external scripts on the front-end.
The $handle variable represents the script's identifier string within the script queue (you will need to find the handle which represents the WC script you want to edit).
The $tag variable contains the actual HTML code for the script tag in string format.
The hook requires that you return the modified $tag variable.
The Solution
Adding the data attribute is actually pretty simple. Just perform "find/replace" on the $tag variable to insert the attribute right before the "src" attribute. Then just return the modified string.
Docs reference
PHP str_replace
WP script_loader_tag hook

Thanks a lot for the answer, your code gave me an error but I tried something else, see edited answer. But that doesn't change anything, what am I doing wrong here?
